# When building a Haskell Reader Arrow, what implementation of "ask" gets rid of the extraneous parameter?

Tags: haskell, arrows

Just got started with Arrows yesterday. As an exercise, I decided to try to build a "Reader Arrow" analogous to `Control.Monad.Reader.Reader`. I've called it `EA` ("Environment Arrow"). Question follows after code.

```hs
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Category
import Control.Arrow
import qualified Data.Bifunctor as BiF

newtype EA r a b = EA { runEA :: r -> a -> b }

instance Arrow (EA r) where
  arr f = EA $ const f
  first (EA f) = EA $ BiF.first . f
  second (EA f) = EA $ BiF.second . f

instance Category (EA r) where
  id = arr id
  (EA b) . (EA a) = EA $ \r -> b r . a r

ask :: EA r a r 
ask = EA const

test :: EA Int Int Int
test = proc i -> do
  f <- ask -< i -- How can I build an "ask" that doesn't need a parameter?
  returnA -< f
```

How can I build `ask` so that it works with `proc` notation but does not need a parameter? In other words, I want to say `f <- ask` and not `f <- ask -< i`, since the parameter is never used.

Comment: Perhaps `ask` should be something like `ask :: E r () r`, but that still does not solve the problem completely.

Comment: I'm not sure why you see a “problem” here. The arrow style is supposed to look more category-like. In general categories, the idea of “constant values” doesn't make sense. Only in [well-pointed categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-pointed_category) can you have such “constants”, represented as arrows from the terminal object – i.e. an arrow of the form `() ~> r`, which does correspond to `EA r () r` in your case.

Comment: Thanks, @leftaroundabout, you inspired me to look more into category theory. I have absolutely **zero** math background beyond high school. When I wrote this question, I didn't know category theory from a hole in the wall. Now I know that it's not a hole in the wall, but not much else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done. `f <- ask` isn't even valid *syntax* in arrow notation. Every arrow must be "applied" to some argument in a `proc` block.

Comment: I suspected as much, but wanted to hear it from those more knowledgeable than I.

Comment: In practice, I think the right thing to do here is to write `ask :: EA r () r` and use `f <- ask -< ()`, rather than permitting arbitrary dummy parameters to be passed around.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Yes, if you look at the first comment on my question, I'd guessed as much, though isn't it less composable that way, if for example I wanted to use `>>>`?

Comment: Oops, missed your comment.  But, yes, I think that's the idea.  It *should* be less composable, because `ask` takes no arrow "input" and so shouldn't be casually composed with something that provides it with an arrow "output" of arbitrary type.  Here, the type system should be leveraged to help you avoid connecting arrow inputs to outputs in potentially erroneous ways.  If you actually intend to connect `ask` this way, then a `proc`-block that makes the nature of the connection explicit would probably be better.